# Laravel Mix version adds references to scss files in js

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have the following configuration in my webpack.mix.js file (Laravel Mix v2.1.14):

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/test.scss', 'public/dist/css')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
    .version();
```

If I ommit the "version()" function, the "app.js" file looks correct, but as soon as I add the "version()" function a reference to the "test.scss" file is added to the app.js file as follows:

```
/***/ "./resources/assets/test.scss":
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ 0:
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__("./resources/assets/js/app.js");
module.exports = __webpack_require__("./resources/assets/test.scss");
```

This happens for every additional scss file that I parse. Does anyone know why the scss file is being added to my js file?

Answer (score 0):

It will be stripped away once you run `npm run production`, but it looks like it might be added by the Version task when it enables the NamedModulesPlugin?

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/21e6742/src/components/Version.js#L41

Comment: I tried it in production mode, the impact of the extra code is minimized a bit but it is still present (as an empty function). For example
`mOet: function(n, t) {},`. The "NamedModulesPlugin" only seems to have an effect on the value of the parameter (full name or hashed).

Comment: After some more research it seems like it is not related to the versioning after all. If I disable the versioning, the empty functions are still present but in a different format:
`/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ })`

Comment: I guess it still explains why version() makes the filename appear